# Adding Click Event Handler onto Multiple Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am fairly new to javascript and HTML5, so excuse me if it turns out to be a silly mistake

I am drawing 3 canvas programmatically with some text and a rectangle and i want a click event on each one of them, also I need to know which canvas has been clicked, i wrote the following code but doMouseDown function is executed even without click

```
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="452" height="80" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="452" height="80" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="452" height="80" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

       <script>
        function init()
        {
            var rect = { w: 300, h: 60 };
            var point = { x: 150, y: 10 };

            for (var i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
                var canvasStr = "myCanvas" + Number(i);
                var c = document.getElementById(canvasStr);
                var context = c.getContext("2d");

                // text
                context.font = "22pt Arial";
                context.lineWidth = 2;
                context.fillStyle = "#000000";

                var studentStr = "Student " + Number(i);
                context.fillText(studentStr, 5, 50);

                // rectangle
                context.strokeStyle = "black";
                context.strokeRect(point.x, point.y, rect.w, rect.h);

                context.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
                context.fillRect(point.x, point.y, rect.w, rect.h);
                c.addEventListener('mousedown', doMouseDown(canvasStr), false);
            }
        }

        function doMouseDown(canvasStr)
        {
            alert(canvasStr);
        }

        init();
    </script>
```

How can i fix it and know which canvas has been clicked (canvasStr in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
c.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
                    doMouseDown(canvasStr)
                }, false);
```

and then write in that function

```
 function doMouseDown(canvasStr) {
             alert(canvasStr);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're attaching listeners in a loop, you have to create a closure, otherwise `canvasStr` will allways be == `myCanvas3`:

```
(function(str) {
    c.addEventListener('mousedown', doMouseDown.bind(str), false);
}(canvasStr));
```

Then your callback should be:

```
function doMouseDown(e, canvasStr) {
    alert(canvasStr);
}
```

First argument `e` is the `Event` object which is always passed to callbacks.

**ADDED**
There is no point in doing this:

```
var canvasStr = "myCanvas" + Number(i);
```

`i` is already a number and you are adding it to a string. Just write:

```
var canvasStr = "myCanvas" + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another way is to wrap all 3 canvases in a container div and listen for events on the container**

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/g7fsS/

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="45" height="80"></canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="45" height="80"></canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="45" height="80"></canvas>
</div>           


document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
},false);
```